# C# .net kestrel server middleware

Tags: c#, middleware, kestrel

The Restful Api development was carried out through the net kestrel server, and the access log and user tracking log for the web page should be recorded in the DB. Java is the main language, and Java has adopted an interceptor method, but I understand that C# has middleware. Data that do not use query strings try to leave a user log by reading the body of the request. Is there any disadvantage

```
Startup.cs

option.AddPolicy("LogHistory", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new LogHistory()));
```

```
LogHistory.cs

public class LogHistory : IAuthorizationRequirement { public LogHistory() { } }
    
    public class LogHistoryHandler : AuthorizationHandler<LogHistory>
    { ... }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear (at least to to me) exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to use middleware to write all logs about CRUD accessed by user to DB. I want to ask if there are any downsides to using middleware and copying the body.

Answer (score 0):

Its not that simple. You can use middleware for this, but it will track all requests to your api, even to non existing endpoints.

If you want to intercept only CRUD methods, I strongly suggest using endpoint filters [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Filters are called after all middlewares and right before endpoint is executed.

Comment: It doesn't just intercept the method, it also needs the data the user has acted on. Therefore, I would like to know the disadvantages of copying the text in middleware.